# Unrecognized selector sent to instance after adding a view controller to a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, custom-view, unrecognized-selector

I have a custom view controller with a custom segue.

When I try to launch the application it crashes with an `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UtilizationVC setUtilizationManager:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
error immediately.

The breakpoint throws at the following line which is in my `AppDelegate` inside of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

LINE REFERENCED: `utilizationVC.utilizationManager = self.utilizationManager;`

My related classes .m and .h files:

UtilizationVC.h:

```
 @class UtilizationVC;

@protocol UtilizationVCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)UtilizationVCDidCancel: (UtilizationVC *)controller;
- (void)UtilizationVCDidDelete: (UtilizationVC *)controller;
- (void)UtilizationVCDidSave: (UtilizationVC *)controller;

@end

@interface UtilizationVC : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <UtilizationVCDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *identifier;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end
```

UtilizationVC.m:

```
#import "UtilizationVC.h"

@interface UtilizationVC ()

@end

@implementation UtilizationVC
{
    UIColor *custom1;
    UIColor *custom2;
    UIColor *custom3;
    UIColor *custom4;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    custom1 = [UIColor whiteColor];
    custom2 = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    custom3 = [UIColor blackColor];
    //custom4 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:.925 blue:.5451 alpha:1.0];
    //custom4 = [UIColor colorWithRed:.7843 green:.7451 blue:.3725 alpha:1.0];
    custom4 = [UIColor colorWithRed:.97 green:.97 blue:.588 alpha:1.0];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[custom2 CGColor], (id)[custom1 CGColor], (id)[custom2 CGColor], nil];
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = view;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

@end

UtilizationManager.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "UtilizationVC.h"

@interface UtilizationManagerVC : UITableViewController
@property (weak,nonatomic) UtilizationManagerVC* utilizationManager;
@end
```

UtilizationManager.m:

```
#import "UtilizationManagerVC.h"

@interface UtilizationManagerVC ()
@end

@implementation UtilizationManagerVC
@synthesize utilizationManager = _utilizationManager;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor *custom1 = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIColor *custom2 = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[custom2 CGColor], (id)[custom1 CGColor], (id)[custom2 CGColor], nil];
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = view;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}
```

@end

I am not sure as to why this is breaking on launch as it was a simple copypaste from another story board and a simple change of the name of the header files.

EDIT:

```
UINavigationController *utilizationNavController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:6];
   UtilizationManagerVC *utilizationVC = [[utilizationNavController viewControllers]objectAtIndex0];
utilizationVC.utilizationManager = self.utilizationManager;
```

ERROR THROWN HERE
this utilizationVC is of type UtilizationManagerVC poor naming on whoever programmed this chunk.

Comment: Read the error. You are trying to set the `utilizationManager` property on an instance of `UtilizationVC` instead of an instance of `UtilizationManagerVC`.

Comment: UtilizationVC is just a variable name of a utilizationManager. Just bad naming scheme (I didn't program this). I will edit in more details.

Comment: The variable name has nothing to do with it. Again, read the error message. You are setting the property on the wrong kind of class.

Comment: Note that you should never name a property or variable with a leading cap.  Reserve leading caps for class names, to help avoid this sort of confusion.  (And @rmaddy is quite right.)

Comment: @HotLicks Haha I realize he's right; and I would never program in this manner... It's crappy I agree however reprogramming an entire infrastructure that was already made this way doesn't leave much for motivation to fix someone else's mistakes. Literally hundreds of bad programming conventions like this throughout the program.

Comment: My second comment was merely a question of clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `utilizationManager` instance in your `UtilizationVC`, **but you don't have any property in that class**. For this reason the app crashes.

I think you commit an error because you put the property:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) UtilizationManagerVC* utilizationManager;
```

in the `UtilizationManagerVC`..so a class that has as property an object typed with the same class?? Maybe you want put this property in your `UtilizationVC`.

Other cool suggests:

- Your `utilizationManager` property should be `strong`, for what particular reason are you using `weak`?
- If you declare a `@property`, you don't need to `synthesize` it, because is `authosynthesized` with the name `_nameProperty`. So until when you don't want use another name, you don't need to `@synthesize` a `@proeprty`.